# How do I keep TCP/IP socket open in IIS?

Tags: asp.net, sockets, iis, tcpclient

I have the following use scenario: User logs in to ASP.NET application; and at some point makes a connection to remote TCP/IP server. The server's response may come after significant delay (say, a few hours). Imagine that the user submits a batch job, and the job may be running for a long time. So, the user may close the browser, get some coffee and come back to see the results later.

However, if client closes the connection, the server will *never* return the results. So, keeping Socket info in Application object won't work - once user closes the browser, it goes away.

Is there any other way to persist this open socket while IIS is up? Also, if the second user logs in, I would prefer to use the same connection. Finally, I realize that the solution is brittle, and it may occasionally break. It's OK.

Remote server is 20-year old mainframe application; so no chance for changes there. And as long as the user doesn't log out - everything is working fine now. Everything is on the LAN, so there are no routing issues to complicate the situation.

Comment: you can use a cookie with a GUID to re-establish a connection for a previous session. i wouldn't recommend holding session open for that long, and if they're broken for any other reason. or sql sessionstate tracking or something. cookie is simpler. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms526029%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: The problem with the cookies (if I understand your suggestion correctly) that it doesn't solve the root problem. Once the user closes the browser, Application object is destroyed and connection is closed. There is no "re-establishing" connection. So, I am not sure how cookie would help...

Comment: Why would application state go away when a user logs out? That doesn't sound right. You have a bug there. Fix it, and this will work (in a brittle way, but you say that's ok).

Comment: that is true, i just re-read OP and noticed. lol... still need some sort of auth to maintain state across pool recycles, session timeouts, etc... (unless not necessary). still, can implement cookie-based auth in an afternoon.

Comment: @usr - I misunderstood Microsoft documentation. Do you mind putting it as an answer, so I can accept it? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contents of the application dictionary are not lost when a user logs out. Your scheme  will work (in a brittle way, but you say that's ok).

Note, that worker processes can exit for many reasons, so expect to be killed at arbitrary points in time.

Comment: i wouldn't suppose application state can also re-establish session auto-magically without a cookie? ;p

Answer (score 0):

you have several options for persisting session-state: [MSDN - Session-State Modes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178586%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

- **inproc mode**: you disconnect, state is lost. if you use cookies, and
  store info/data somewhere on the backend, then you can map the GUID
  to the data, regardless of session. or use application-state.
- **stateserver**: persisted across disconnects and application restarts,
  but not across iis/pool/server restarts, unless you use another
  server, or cookie/auth. can be problematic sometimes.
- **sqlserver**: as the name implies, uses a specially formatted db/table structure to persist state data across all sorts of scenarios.
- **custom/off**: allows you to build your own provider, or turns it off completely.

here's the cookie method, by far the simplest (you have to generate a GUID, then store it in the cookie and application state or a backend DB): [MSDN - Maintaining Session State with Cookies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms526029%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

> you can persist cookies on the user's client. then, on server
>   reboot/client disconnect/any other scenario just pull the GUID from
>   app/session state or from a backend DB, which will also store the data
>   for the reports/output.

also, as a caution: even though cookies can be used to auth a user to an account/db record via GUID, it is considered insecure for all other purposes except unindentifiable information, such as: view shopping cart, simple reports, status, etc...

oh, and the stuff on IIS session timeouts (20 mins by default): [MSDN - Configure Session Time-out (IIS 7)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725820%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) and [MSDN - Configure Idle Time-out Settings for an Application Pool (IIS 7)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771956%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

completely forgot to add the links on: [ASP.NET Application State Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178594%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), [ASP.NET Session State Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178581%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), but storing large amounts of data on a busy server in application state is not recommended. oh yea, and [MSDN - Caching Application Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6hbbsfk6%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)