# ASP.NET how to pass a reference to a particular control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, postback, web-controls, dopostback

I'm generally an ASP.NET MVC guy, so the "standard" ASP.NET stuff is a little difficult for me to wrap my brain around.  I've tried looking for the answer, but the keywords I'm using seem to be too generic... I get a lot of *close* answers, but not what I'm actually looking for.

I have a grid that is populated from a data set.  One of the fields is a dropdown with 4 possible statuses.  When the user selects a status, an event is fired in the codebehind to make the change in the db immediately.

There is a particular status that I need to confirm, because once it's selected, it's irreversible.  Figuring out how to have the back end pop up a confirmation box was annoying, but I think I have that part done now.

The problem is, if the user confirms that the status they selected for the dropdown was intended, I need to disable any further changes to that dropdown, either by disabling the control or by removing the row altogether.  With this requirement, I imagine I need to  pass a reference to the specific control that fired the event back to the script, so that it can pass it through the postback, where I would need to consume it.

I have no idea how to pass a reference to the control (what can be used as a reference?) and I have no idea how to use that reference in the postback.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seriously?  19 view and nothing?  Maybe I should rewrite this as an MVC app.

Comment: Without being able to see how you have constructed your grid it is difficult. I would say that in the dropdown selectedindexchanged event you would have some code that set the dropdown to be disabled if its value was your specified value.

Comment: problem is I have to prompt the user to confirm first.

Comment: Correct so you have javascript that intercepts the dropdown change first. If the value is the one that needs confirming it pops up a confirm action request. If confirmed the server side selectedindexchanged code is allowed to run. If cancelled then the server side event is not run. Plenty of examples of this type of javascript function available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

;p i was waiting for you to find my post on the issue lol.

but to put it simply, you postback to the page, all members are still available to you if you instantiated something in codebehind. if not, then use `FindControl` to pull them from `DOM`. here's the passing values stuff.

as long as you don't kill the lifecycle, you're fine: [Passing dropdownlist selected value to another page's dropdown list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23923768/passing-dropdownlist-selected-value-to-another-pages-dropdown-list/23924069#23924069)

and here is the linkspam (full docs): [How do I keep TCP/IP socket open in IIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23852626/how-do-i-keep-tcp-ip-socket-open-in-iis/23853851#23853851)

probably the articles on session-state and page lifecycle will be of most use.

Answer (score 0):

To prompt the user for confirm add this attribute to dropdownlist.

```
onchange="return confirm('Confirmation Message');"
```